# Window created using javascript do not fire onbeforeunload when using window.close()

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of `javascript code`:

```
var certWin = window.open('/admin/Includes/certCreator.php', '', 'width=200, height=100');

certWin.onbeforeunload = function() {

 var bodyHtml = $(certWin.document).find('body').html(),
     json = $.parseJSON(bodyHtml);

  if ( json['error'] ) {
    appMainStatusBar.setError(json['error']);
  }

}
```

`certCreator.php` will return a `JSON` value if any error is found or will download a zip archive if all goes the right way.

The code will open up a new window and will stay there untill the user closes it, of course we do not want that. If I do close the window the `appMainStatusBar` object will show the error found...

But when I add this:

`echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>"`

To the `certCreator.php` file. It will close the window but the error will not be shown on the `appMainStatusBar` object. It is like the `onbeforeunload` event do not fire.

Comment: Race condition? What if you do `setTimeout(window.close, 3000)` instead? That should give things enough time for the `onbeforeunload` event to be attached.

Comment: I can not do a timeout on window.close because there is no way to know if  the script is running... The script creates members certificates, and it might take a very long or a very short time to create all the needed certicates.

Comment: @Jack Well I added the timeout and still it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it.!

Problem was that I was targetting the page entire body, so everytime the event was fired it got something like this:

```
{"error":"Options are not set"} <script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>
```

That was stored in the `bodyHtml` var as string and then I tried to parse that as JSON, of course that will not parse. That is not a valid string to parse.

I changed `var bodyHtml` to `var resultsHtml = $(certWin.document).find('#results').html();`

And in the `certCreator.php` page I changed to:

```
echo "<div id='results'>";
echo json_encode($returned);
echo "</div>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>";
```

I wish this will be helpfull for someone else.